# Get current user email meteor

Tags: meteor, profile

I am having a bit of difficulty getting the email of the current user in Meteor.

publish.js

```
Meteor.publish('allUsers', function(){
if(Roles.userIsInRole(this.userId, 'admin')) {
return Meteor.users.find({});   
    }
});

Meteor.publish('myMail', function(){ {
    return Meteor.user().emails[0].address; 
    }
});
```

profile.html

```
<template name="Profile">
    <h1> My Profile </h1>
    {{#if currentUser}}
<p>{{currentUser.profile.firstName}}</p> <p>{{currentUser.roles}}</p>
<p>{{currentUser.userEmail}}</p>
{{/if}}
</template>
```

profile.js

```
Template.Profile.helpers({
    users: function() {
        return Meteor.users.find();
    },
    userEmail: function() {
        return Meteor.user().emails[0].address;
        }
});
```

Firstname and ._id display fine, emailaddress unfortunately does not. Does anyone have a tip? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `'myMail` publication is both redundant and incorrect. You should either return a cursor (or an array of cursors), or observe a cursor and send handle the publication lifecycle yourself (a fairly advanced feature, irrelevant to your question). You are using it a-la `Meteor.methods`, and you should not really user `Meteor.user()` in a publication anyway.

It's redundant because Meteor's accounts package publishes the current user's `emails` field automatically.

In your template, you are treating `userEmail` as an attribute of the current user, instead of calling it as a helper.

I would advise to use a guard and make sure that the user actually has an email address, something in the lines of:

JS:

```js
Template.Profile.helpers({
  users: function() {
    return Meteor.users.find();
  },
  userEmail: function(user) {
    if (user.emails && user.emails.length > 0) {
      return user.emails[0].address;
    }
    return 'no email';
  }
});
```

HTML:

```html
<template name="Profile">
    <h1> My Profile </h1>
    {{#if currentUser}}
    <p>{{currentUser.profile.firstName}}</p> <p>{{currentUser.roles}}</p>
    <p>{{userEmail currentUser}}</p>
    {{/if}}
</template>
```

I would also strongly advise against publishing all of the fields in the `'allUsers'` publication, as it will expose sensitive data that should not leave the server under almost any circumstances (e.g, password data).